# Get all Facebook friends in one Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieve all of a user's facebook friends with the `installed` field for my app. With facebook's graph api, it paginates the response, but I don't want to have to make multiple requests per user. Is there a way to do `https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/friends?fields=installed&access_token=<access_token>` to get all friends and not paginated?

If you are wondering, I am using this data to reconstruct a friend graph for my application.

Comment: Set a higher `limit` then the default (which is 25, I think).

Comment: I tried `https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/friends?fields=installed&limit=999999&access_token=<access_token>` Is that the correct way to do it? It still returns a "next" url, though I didn't check that it actually returned 999999 results, so how do I know that I've received all data? Shouldn't it say: {next: null}?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `limit` to the call to increase the number of results you get. E.g.:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/friends?fields=installed&access_token=<access_token>&limit=1000`